# Proof that operator is an isometry

Tags: operator-algebras

A linear operator $L$ between complex spaces with inner product $U$ and $V$ is an isometry, only if $\left < Lu_i, Lu_j \right > =  \left < u_i, u_j \right >$ for all $u_j, u_i$ from a basis of $U$ (not necessary orthonormal).

I would like to see a proof of this statement.

Comment: Use the polarization identity.

Comment: Are $U$ and $V$ assumed to be finite dimensional? If not, you'll need to clearly specify what you mean by basis if you don't mean orthonormal basis.  (It would be false as stated in infinite dimensions with an orthonormal basis.  If you mean Hamel basis then it's fine I think.)

Comment: Can you prove it without using the polarization identity?

Comment: @julien I think it just means a complex, inner product space.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. Never heard that term before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT***: ONLY IF direction proof without directly referring the polarization identity is as follows.

First we know that
$$
\|Lu_m\|^2_V = \langle L u_m ,L u_m\rangle = \|u_m\|^2_U = \langle   u_m , u_m\rangle\tag{1}
$$
because of isometry. Now there is:
$$
\|L(u_m-u_n)\|^2_V = \langle L(u_m-u_n) , L(u_m-u_n) \rangle  = \langle  u_m-u_n  ,  u_m-u_n \rangle  = \|u_m-u_n\|_U^2.\tag{2}
$$
Expanding and using (1) lead to
$$
\langle L u_m, Lu_n \rangle + \langle L u_n, Lu_m\rangle = \langle  u_m  ,  u_n \rangle + \langle  u_n  ,  u_m \rangle\tag{3}
$$
Change (2) a little bit:
$$
\|L(u_m-iu_n)\|^2_V = \langle L(u_m-iu_n) , L(u_m-iu_n) \rangle  = \langle  u_m-iu_n  ,  u_m-iu_n \rangle  = \|u_m-iu_n\|_U^2.
$$
Similarly we have:
$$
\langle L u_m,i Lu_n \rangle + \langle i L u_n, Lu_m\rangle = \langle  u_m  ,  i u_n \rangle + \langle i u_n  ,  u_m \rangle,
$$
and this is 
$$
-i \langle L u_m, Lu_n \rangle + i\langle  L u_n, Lu_m\rangle = -i\langle  u_m  ,  u_n \rangle + i\langle u_n  ,  u_m \rangle,
$$
cancelling $-i$ we have:
$$
 \langle L u_m, Lu_n \rangle -\langle  L u_n, Lu_m\rangle =  \langle  u_m  ,  u_n \rangle -\langle u_n  ,  u_m \rangle.\tag{4}
$$
(3)+(4) gives the result you want.

---

<s>Following is the if direction proof :</s> (deleted)

EDIT 2: Thanks Jonas Meyer pointed out here, the if direction presumes the space has a Schauder basis, i.e., at least separable. By OP only said it is an inner product space, we can't do that.

Comment: How could one get from $\left < Lu_i, Lu_j \right > =  \left < u_i, u_j \right >$ to $\|Lu_k\| = \|u_k\|$ to complete the proof?

Comment: @Ben I didn't mean this expression means directly isometry, I use an expansion w.r.t. this basis for an arbitrary element to prove it. For isometry you wanna prove it for arbitrary two elements.

Comment: I saw somewhere that you could get from condition $\left < Lu_i, Lu_j \right > =  \left < u_i, u_j \right >$ to $\|Lu_k\| = \|u_k\|$. Maybe something with the polarization identity?

Comment: @Ben I was reading your question wrong just now, please see my edit.

Comment: Ben would not clarify what "basis" means, if it does not mean orthonormal basis and the space is infinite dimensional.  This answer assumes that it allows one to write $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i u_i$, presumably intended to mean a norm convergent series.    I'm don't know what basis is taken to mean in this answer.  Schauder basis?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you very much for pointing out my conceptual mistake. I have deleted the if direction proof.